# jQuery selecting invisible tr even blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a big table, and some of its `<tr>` elements are hidden `display: none`. I am trying to select all `visible` blocks with jquery, and add a css style to them. I tried something like so:

```
$('#table tr').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');  //give all rows white background
$('#table tr:visible').filter(':even').css('background-color', 'rgb(242, 242, 242)'); //select all even VISIBLE blocks, and add gray color to them
```

For some reason my current code colors all even tr blocks, even the ones that are invisible. How can i improve my code? Wheres the mistake?

Edit:
I also tried something like this:

```
 $('#table tr:visible').filter(':even').css('background-color', 'rgb(242, 242, 242)');
  $('#table tr:visible').filter(':odd').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
```

Again, it colors even the invisible blocks..

Comment: Prepare a fiddle to replicate... and paste your relevant markup in the question.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sJTf8/1/

Comment: Are you sure you are hiding tr itself and not its td.. http://jsfiddle.net/8MJDe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
// white background for odd rows
$('#table tr:odd').css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'); 
//select all even VISIBLE blocks, and add gray color to them
$('#table tr:visible:even').css('background-color', 'rgb(242, 242, 242)'); 

//or if you have hidden class for hidden rows then you can use like,
$('#table tr:even').not('.hiddenclass')
                   .css('background-color', 'rgb(242, 242, 242)');
```

Comment: It still colors the hidden rows

Comment: @Edgar Have you applied any class on hidden rows?

Comment: @Rohan, yeah each row has classes

Comment: @Edgar Test the above answer, now.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that according to the [jquery docs on :visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), any element with a width and height is considered visible even if it has visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 set.

You should probably set a class on the visible tr elements (if you aren't already) and select based on that class instead, for example something like "#table .visible:even"